# Execute multiple methods in one method

Tags: java, swing

Hello i need one button for checks which to call another methods with step checks and if there is error in one of them to display it.I made it but it returns me the message of the last called method and if i i have error it doesn't  return error becouse at the moment he returns the message of the last method

Code for the button:

```
   private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    connect1();
    try {
        Check1();
        Check2();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And code of the Chech1 method and Check2 method:

```
    private Integer Check1() throws SQLException {
    Integer records = 0;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    connect1();
    String query = "select count(*) from MSISDNs_for_Import (nolock)\n"
            + " where len(msisdn) <> 12 or len(sim) <> 12  or msisdn not like '35988%'";
    pstmt = conn1.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        records = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("COUNT= " + records);
        selectedFilesField.setText("Check 1 successfull");
        rs.close();
        if (records > 1) {
            selectedFilesField.setText("Error in check 1");
        }
    }

    return records;
}

private Integer Check2() throws SQLException {
    Integer records = 0;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    connect1();
    String query = "select count(*) from SIMs_for_Import  (nolock)\n"
            + " where substring(imsi, 8, 1) <> '6'";
    pstmt = conn1.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        records = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("COUNT= " + records);
        selectedFilesField.setText("Check 2 successfull");
        rs.close();
        if (records > 1) {
            selectedFilesField.setText("Error in check 2");
        }
    }
    return records;
}
```

At the moment it works if i have one button for every chech but i need to combine them in one button..

Comment: and ... what is stopping you?

Comment: In check1 it retturns error but when he step in check2 it is successsfull and it shows me message checks are successfull,but they actually are not...

Comment: where is `selectedFilesField` defined?

Comment: so your problem has nothing to do with calling the methods, it'syour code?

Comment: it is a text box which shows text to the user nothing more

Comment: it would be useful to know what type the `selectedFilesField` is and in which method/class is defined

Comment: make question is why when check 1 has message error in check 1 a whent it call check2 message and it is successfull messagebox show check 2 successfull,my expectations are error in checking

Comment: `check2` method overrides the message written by `check1` method, so instead of displaying the message from `check2` method, collect all messages (from both `check1` and `check2` methods) in a `List` or something similar and display all the messages after both `check1` and `check2` finish running

Answer (score 0):

You can make your both methods returns integer instead and restructure your code this way.

```
    private Integer Check1() throws SQLException {
    Integer records = 0;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    connect1();
    String query = "select count(*) from MSISDNs_for_Import (nolock)\n"
            + " where len(msisdn) <> 12 or len(sim) <> 12  or msisdn not like '35988%'";
    pstmt = conn1.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        records = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("COUNT= " + records);
        selectedFilesField.setText("Check 1 successfull");
        rs.close();
    }

    return records;
}

private Integer Check2() throws SQLException {
    Integer records = 0;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    connect1();
    String query = "select count(*) from SIMs_for_Import  (nolock)\n"
            + " where substring(imsi, 8, 1) <> '6'";
    pstmt = conn1.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        records = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("COUNT= " + records);
        selectedFilesField.setText("Check 2 successfull");
        rs.close();
    }
    return records;
}
```

then your actual code will be like,

```
private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    connect1();
    try {
        if( Check1() > 0 ) {
           if( Check2() > 0 ) {
              //Do Something
           } else {
              selectedFilesField.setText("Error in check 2");
           }
        } else {
           selectedFilesField.setText("Error in check 1");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can also write it like this:

```
private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    connect1();
    try {
        int i = Check1();
if(i < 0){
selectedFilesField.setText("Error in check 1");
}else{

        Check2();
}
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

By this way you can directly set the error message from check 1 if the check 1 fails and check 2 if check 2 fails and check 1 succeed.